# Acid that ''dissolves'' water

Tags: creature-design

Animal spits/releases various chems, they mix and create an acid capable of separating water into hydrogen and oxygen, this potentially results in an explosion.

Is this possible?

[yes]-[no]

please explain the reason for your answer.

Comment: Decomposing water into hydrogen and oxygen requires more energy that what is returned by burning the hydrogen in the oxygen. If the animal has all that energy available, then decomposing water and then recombining the decomposition products is a useless complication. (And please check your terminology; decomposing and dissolving are vastly different things.)

Comment: Public service announcement: For those readers not versed in post-medieval alchemical terminology, the [alkahest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkahest) was a notional universal solvent with rather moddled but generally awesome and wonderful properties. (Note that alchemists in general used a muddled terminology, due partly to the lack of a workable theoretical frameowk and partly to the pervasive intellectual laziness which permeated large swathes of the of European culture of the time.) (No, it is not an Arabic word. Apparently, the word was invented by Paracelsus.)

Comment: @candied_orange ''The problem with a universal solvent is finding something to keep it in.''

Comment: @candied_orange in is the opposite of **EXTERNAL**

Comment: *"An acid capable of separating water into hydrogen and oxygen":* that is **absolutely not** what acids do. On the contrary, when an acid is dissolved in water, it *the water* which extracts hydrogen ions from the acid (forming [hydronium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydronium) ions, $\mathrm H_3{\mathrm O_2}^+$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chemical reaction you are looking for is delightfully titled "[water splitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_splitting)", at least on Wikipedia. The article lists a number of methods, ranging from electrolysis to interaction with certain nanostructures. More methods are being researched for the purposes of getting hydrogen gas to put in fuel cells, so if you want to invent a phlebotinum substance that does the same trick, be my guest. Do call it alkahest rather than acid if you don't want more terminology nerds to get offended.

But one thing your alkahest will need - which all water splitting methods need - is energy. Electrical energy, high temperature, solar energy, etc. Decomposing water is an endothermic process.

People try to decompose water for fuel cells because a fuel cell is a way to store energy. It is like lifting up a big weight: let it drop again to get back (most of) the energy you used to get it up. That's potential energy, and it's useful for human infrastructure but less so for creatures without the way to create fuel cells containing the hydrogen and oxygen, which upon being synthesised would quickly drift away in the atmosphere and make your digestive process even less efficient. In no way will any explosions yield back the effort it took to create the gases.

Now, there's plenty of un-optimised processes in natural life like human retinae being installed the wrong way around, or the panda stubbornly surviving off of low-energy bamboo.

But this particular phenomenon you are describing would not exist in a local optimum: that is because your creature's prey (I assume it is organic) is primarily made of water itself. So any process that can break down water can also break down what the prey itself is made of. Causing explosions as an intermediate step is just inefficient and any animal with a mind would realise that and apply their organ more directly. A few generations of evolution later and this miraculous water decomposition method would be used where it would be far more useful: as a venom. Inject a chemical agent that powerful into a big creature's bloodstream and they won't know what hit them.